# How to convert string as object's field name in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a js object like:

```
obj = {
  name: 'js',
  age: 20
};
```

now i want to access name field of obj, but i can only get string 'name', so how to convert 'name' to obj's field name, then to get result like obj.name.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `obj.name` or am I missing the point of the question?

Comment: @mhitza: Maybe "name" is stored in a variable and they want to access it like `obj.<[evaluate_var]>` where `<[evaluate_var]>` is stored as 'name'?

Comment: @Brad Christie is right.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, these answers are the same and i tried it's correct. Thank you thank you very much.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can access the properties of javascript object using the index i.e.

```
var obj = {
  name: 'js',
  age: 20
};

var isSame = (obj["name"] == obj.name)
alert(isSame);

var nameIndex = "name"; // Now you can use nameIndex as an indexor of obj to get the value of property name.
isSame = (obj[nameIndex] == obj.name)
```

Check example@ : http://www.jsfiddle.net/W8EAr/

Answer (score 21):

In Javascript, `obj.name` is equivalent to `obj['name']`, which adds the necessary indirection.

In your example:

```
var fieldName = 'name'
var obj = {
  name: 'js',
  age: 20
};
var value = obj[fieldName]; // 'js'
```

Answer (score 14):

Not related at all, but for anyone trying to define object's field name from a string variable, you could try with:

```js
const field = 'asdf'
const obj = {[field]: 123}
document.body.innerHTML = obj.asdf
```

Comment: Nice solution!!

Answer (score 8):

It's quite simple, to access an object's value via a variable, you use square brackets:

```
var property = 'name';
var obj = {name: 'js'};
alert(obj[property]); // pops 'js'
```

Answer (score 2):

As objects are associative arrays in javascript you can access the 'name' field as `obj['name']` or `obj[fieldName]` where `fieldName = 'name'`.