# Convert string value to object property name

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert string as object's field name in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841254/how-to-convert-string-as-objects-field-name-in-javascript)

I can do this:

```
var objPosition = {};
objPosition.title = "whatever";
```

But I'm getting 'title' dynamically, and want to use about a half dozen strings so obtained to assign the half dozen properties to the object. I've tried eval and several other schemes that seem to have the same problem, but have come up empty so far.

I have:

```
var txtCol = $(this).text();
txtCol = $.trim(txtCol);
```

and I want the value of txtCol to be a property name.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Use `['propname']`:

```
objPosition[txtCol] = "whatever";
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hr7XW/

Answer (score 15):

use [bracket notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets): `objPosition['title'] = "whatever";`

so:

```
var objPosition = {}, ttl = 'title';
objPosition[ttl] = 'whatever';
```

[edit 11/2019: es20xx]

```js
let objPosition = {};
const ttl = 'title';
// [...]
objPosition = {...objPosition, [ttl]: "whatever"};
console.log(objPosition);
```

Answer (score 4):

you can also set the object's key like this

```
var property = "title"
objPosition[property] = "something";
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the bracket notation like this:

```
objPosition["title"] = "Whatever";
```