# javascript, acessing a json key stored in variable

Tags: javascript, json, variables, dynamic, properties

I've got the following code:

```
function valor_actual(moneda) { 
     var url="https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker";
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url); 
        var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); 
        var dataSet = dataAll;
        var pair= "BTC_"+moneda
        return dataSet.pair.last; 
}
```

This code of couse is not working..

The moneda variable could have different values, for example, "VTC" or "AUR" or .... What i need is if moneda="AUR" return dataSet.BTC_AUR.last property and if moneda="SC" return dataSet.BTC_SC.last property, etc...

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to these questions: [How to convert string as object's field name in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841254/how-to-convert-string-as-objects-field-name-in-javascript) ; [Convert string value to object property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164764/convert-string-value-to-object-property-name)

Try changing your last line to:
`dataSet[pair].last;`

As a side note, based off the code you have given the line:
`var dataSet = dataAll;`
is redundant. The names lead me to believe that `dataSet` is meant to be a subset of `dataAll` but as written `dataSet` is just a copy of `dataAll`. So your code can be simplified to:

```
function valor_actual(moneda) { 
     var url="https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker";
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url); 
        var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); 
        var pair= "BTC_"+moneda
        return dataAll[pair].last; 
}
```