# How to convert object's field name to value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I'm trying to convert an object like `{fieldName: "value"}` into another object like `{field: "fieldName", value: "value"}` in the simplest way possible, without knowing what the fieldName is in advance.

I've looked at the answer to [How to convert string as object's field name in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841254/how-to-convert-string-as-objects-field-name-in-javascript/4841286#4841286) but although this works it relies on the fact that the fieldName is already known. The following works:

```
const key = Object.keys(searchObject)[0];
  return { field: key, value: searchObject[key] }
```

But it looks unwieldy, clunky and error-prone. What I would like is the equivalent of

```
const obj = { field: [searchObject.key], ... }
```

But this only works where `[searchObject.key]` is the *value* of `searchObject.key`.

Comment: You might be interested in [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over each property in your object and create another one with the key and value as separated properties, then push it to a new array and return it.

Example:

```js
var test_data = {fieldName: "name", fieldName2: "name2"}

function convert(data){
  var result = []
  for(var k in data){
    result.push({
      field: k,
      value: data[k]
    })
  }
  return result
}

console.log(convert(test_data))

// ------ ES6 ---------- //

console.log(
  Object.keys(test_data).map(a=>({field: a, value: test_data[a]}))
)
```

Comment: The ES6 looks ok, but I'm trying to avoid an array solution. Perhaps that's the best result.