# return an array containing the value associated with that key for each object

Tags: javascript

As the title states, I am trying to return an array containing the value associated with that key for each object, or undefined if that key is not present.

Here is what I have so far:

```js
function pluck(arr, name) {

permittedValues = arr.map(function(value) {
  return value.key || undefined;
});
}
console.log(
  pluck([
  { name: "Tim" }, { name: "Matt" }, { name: "Elie" }],
 'name'
)
  );
```

I am trying to return something like this:

```
// ["Tim", "Matt", "Elie"]
```

Comment: `value[name]` would be the array syntax

Comment: well pluck returns nothing and what is key?

Comment: `value.key` is the property named `key`, **not** the property named whatever the *value* of `key` is. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/4841254/3001761.

Comment: You have no variable named `key`. Did you mean to write `function pluck(arr, key)`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use indexer to get the property and if it doesn't exist, undefined will be returned:

```
function pluck(arr, name) {
    return arr.map(function (value) {
        return value[name];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to return `value[name] || undefined`, if name key doesn't exist it will return `undefined` anyway.

```js
function pluck(arr, name) {

return permittedValues = arr.map(value => 
  value[name]);
}
console.log(
  pluck([
  { name: "Tim" }, { name: "Matt" }, { name: "Elie" }],
 'name'
)
  );
```

This code can get even more concise using arrow functions

```js
const pluck = (arr, name) => arr.map(value => value[name])

console.log(pluck([{ name: "Tim" }, { name: "Matt" }, { name: "Elie" }],'name'));
```